# Fixing a NoReverseMatch in a Django Project for Registration

Tags: python, django

Hi I keep getting NoReverseMatch at /users/register/
however I am have followed the step by step for fixing this error:

Here is the urls.py

```
app_name = 'tac'

urlpatterns = [
    path('terms-and-conditions/', TermsAndConditionsView.as_view(), namespace='terms_and_conditions'),
    path('user-agreement/', UserAgreementView.as_view(), namespace='user_agreement'),
]
```

Here is the register.html that is causing the error:

```
<label class="form-check-label" for="terms_and_conditions">I agree to the <a href="{% url 'tac:terms_and_conditions' %}">terms and conditions</a>
</label>
```

Here is the traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\users\views.py", line 34, in register
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 62, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 472, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 82, in reverse
    raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" % key)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'tac' is not a registered namespace
[06/Feb/2023 23:11:00] "GET /users/register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 126759
```

here is the main urls.py

```
    path('tac/', include('tac.urls'), ),
```

it is also added in the settings INSTALLED_APPS

My question:
How can I fix this error and why is it appearing?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show code in the main *urls.py* file

Comment: @ManojKamble added the main urls.py

Comment: Not sure if this fixes your exact issue but you should pass `name='...'` to your urlpatterns/paths and not `namespace='...'`

Comment: @IainShelvington I am not sure what is the difference tbh but it fixed the issue. I will have to check the difference between them.

Comment: Hello @A_K I think [`path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/urls/#path) does not have **namespace** argument [`include()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/urls/#django.urls.include) does have

Answer (score 0):

In main urls.py file, instead of
`path('tac/', include('tac.urls'), ),`
add :

`path('tac/', include('tac.urls',namespace="tac"), ),   #You can use any name instead of tac`

Also, In app's urls.py file use `name` instead of `namespace`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('terms-and-conditions/', TermsAndConditionsView.as_view(), name='terms_and_conditions'),
    path('user-agreement/', UserAgreementView.as_view(), name='user_agreement'),
]
```

In your template, you can call it as :

`{% url 'tac:terms_and_conditions' %}`